# Convert generic Json with multiple nested array to a Datatable C#

Tags: c#, json, datatable, converters

I need help, I need a function that recive a Json and returns a Datatable, any input can come in Json format so I can't use a object.
My problem is when the Json comes with multiple Arrays nested in the response (the Json can have any format, it can come without Arrays or it can come with 1 or more Arrays), any idea how to make this possible? I need the algorithm to be as generic as possible. Thanks

I leave an example input and what I expect to get

```
        public const string ResponseThreeArrays = @"{
        ""key1"": ""val1"",
        ""key2"": {
            ""key2-1"": 
            [
                {
                    ""key2-arr1-1"": ""val2-arr1-1(1)"",
                    ""key2-arr1-2"": 
                    [
                        {
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-1(1)(1)"",
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-2"" : 
                            [
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(1)(1)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(1)(1)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(1)(1)""
                                },
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(1)(2)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(1)(2)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(1)(2)""
                                },
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(1)(3)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(1)(3)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(1)(3)""
                                }
                            ],
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-3(1)(1)""
                        },
                        {
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-1(1)(2)"",
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-2"" : 
                            [
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(2)(1)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(2)(1)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(2)(1)""
                                },
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(2)(2)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(2)(2)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(2)(2)""
                                },
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(2)(3)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(2)(3)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(2)(3)""
                                }
                            ],
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-3(1)(2)""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    ""key2-arr1-1"": ""val2-arr1-1(2)"",
                    ""key2-arr1-2"": 
                    [
                        {
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-1(2)(1)"",
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-2"" : 
                            [
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(1)(1)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(1)(1)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(1)(1)""
                                },
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(1)(2)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(1)(2)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(1)(2)""
                                 },
                                 {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(1)(3)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(1)(3)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(1)(3)""
                                 }
                            ],
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-3(2)(1)""
                        },
                        {
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-1(2)(2)"",
                            ""key2-arr1-arr2-2"" : 
                            [
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(2)(1)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(2)(1)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(2)(1)""
                                },
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(2)(2)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(2)(2)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(2)(2)""
                                },
                                {
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(2)(3)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(2)(3)"",
                                    ""key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(2)(3)""
                                }
                            ],
                           ""key2-arr1-arr2-3"" : ""val2-arr1-arr2-3(2)(2)""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            ""key2-2"" : ""val2-2""
            },
        ""key3"": ""val3""
        }";
```

And this is what I expect obtain:

[Datatable expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7yR7.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: So, an infinitely recursive flattening algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library to do such conversion easily. (Not sure, this meets your requirement)

```
using (var r = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(ResponseThreeArrays)
       .ErrorMode(ChoErrorMode.IgnoreAndContinue)
      )
{
    var dt = r.FlattenBy("key2", "key2-1", "key2-arr1-2", "key2-arr1-arr2-2").AsDataTable();
    dt.Print();
}
```

**Output:**

```
key1,key3,key2-2,key2-arr1-1,key2-arr1-arr2-1,key2-arr1-arr2-3,key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1,key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2,key2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(1),val2-arr1-arr2-1(1)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-3(1)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(1)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(1)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(1)(1)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(1),val2-arr1-arr2-1(1)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-3(1)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(1)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(1)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(1)(2)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(1),val2-arr1-arr2-1(1)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-3(1)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(1)(3),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(1)(3),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(1)(3)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(1),val2-arr1-arr2-1(1)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-3(1)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(2)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(2)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(2)(1)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(1),val2-arr1-arr2-1(1)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-3(1)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(2)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(2)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(2)(2)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(1),val2-arr1-arr2-1(1)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-3(1)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(1)(2)(3),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(1)(2)(3),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(1)(2)(3)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(2),val2-arr1-arr2-1(2)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-3(2)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(1)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(1)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(1)(1)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(2),val2-arr1-arr2-1(2)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-3(2)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(1)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(1)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(1)(2)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(2),val2-arr1-arr2-1(2)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-3(2)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(1)(3),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(1)(3),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(1)(3)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(2),val2-arr1-arr2-1(2)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-3(2)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(2)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(2)(1),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(2)(1)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(2),val2-arr1-arr2-1(2)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-3(2)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(2)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(2)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(2)(2)
val1,val3,val2-2,val2-arr1-1(2),val2-arr1-arr2-1(2)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-3(2)(2),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-1(2)(2)(3),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-2(2)(2)(3),val2-arr1-arr2-arr3-3(2)(2)(3)
```

**Sample fiddle:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/wnacwN

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is partly what I want but the problem is that the Json can come in any format, I can't define the arguments of the "FlattenBy" function, I leave the code of what I have so far, the function has a filter the columns that I want my datatable to have

Comment: This obviously not the most elegant way to handle that, but if all you need are the keys to pass to the library, you can use LINQ to get them. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/nbVSak for a hastily modified version of what @Cinchoo wrote for you

Answer (score 0):

I leave here what I have so far, @Cinchoo

```
public DataTable MapJson(string json)
    {
        var jo = JToken.Parse(json);
        var stringReader = new StringReader(MakeConfigString(jo));
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTableConfig));
        var config = (DataTableConfig)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        foreach (var p in config.Property)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(p.Name);
        }

        var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("*"));

        var count = 0;
        if (jo is JArray)
        {
            count = jo.Count();
        }
        else if (jo is JObject jsonLinq)
        {
            count = jsonLinq.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d is JArray)?.Count() ?? 1;
        }

        var dataCollection = Enumerable.Range(0, count)
            .Select(x => config.Property
                .Select(prop => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>
                (
                    prop.Name,
                    jo.SelectTokens(regex.Replace(prop.Path, x.ToString(), 1)).Select(c => c.Value<string>()).ToList())
                ));


        foreach (var data in dataCollection)
        {
            var countMax = data.Select(x => x.Value).Max(x => x.Count);

            for (var i = 0; i < countMax; i++)
            {
                var innerList = new List<object>();
                foreach (var prop in config.Property)
                {
                    var currentData = data.Where(x => x.Key == prop.Name).SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();

                    if (currentData.Any())
                    {

                        if (i >= currentData.Count)
                        {
                            innerList.Add(currentData.Last());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            innerList.Add(currentData[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        innerList.Add("");
                    }
                }

                dataTable.Rows.Add(innerList.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
        private string MakeConfigString(JToken json)
    {
        var result = @"<DataTableConfig Name='DataTable'>";

        foreach (var col in this.ApiConnectorsColumns)
        {
            var path = json is JArray ? col.PathNode.Replace(".Columns", "[*]") : col.PathNode.Remove(0, 9);
            var temp = $"<Property Name='{col.ColumnName}' Path='{path}'/>";
            result += temp;
        }

        result += "</DataTableConfig>";

        return result;
    }
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Property")]
public class Property
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataTableConfig")]
public class DataTableConfig
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Property")]
    public List<Property> Property { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unless this solves your question, this should be edited into your original question. Otherwise, members of the community will think that you've solved your own problem since you posted an answer, and may be less inclined to take the time to offer their own answers.